# How to consume kafka message from server with offset value?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topicName --from-beginning --max-messages 10`

and it gives me 10 messages but i want to that message with that specific message offset value like:

`kafka-message 1234` where `kafka-message` is kafka message and `1234` is offset value.

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435230/retrieve-a-message-by-knowing-its-partition-and-offset-in-kafka

Comment: @cricket_007 Can you please provide me command for this?

Comment: @bain2236 there is no command to run at server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`kafkacat -f '%s %o'`](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat)

```
Format string tokens:
  %s                 Message payload
  %S                 Message payload length (or -1 for NULL)
  %R                 Message payload length (or -1 for NULL) serialized
                     as a binary big endian 32-bit signed integer
  %k                 Message key
  %K                 Message key length (or -1 for NULL)
  %T                 Message timestamp (milliseconds since epoch UTC)
  %h                 Message headers (n=v CSV)
  %t                 Topic
  %p                 Partition
  %o                 Message offset
  \n \r \t           Newlines, tab
  \xXX \xNNN         Any ASCII character
 Example:
  -f 'Topic %t [%p] at offset %o: key %k: %s\n'
```